# rqt_graph colors and arrows

Tags: rosnode, rqt-graph, rosservices, rostopic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the color code for rqt_graph?
And do the bi-directional arrows mean a service between two nodes or just that the node subscribes to AND publishes to the other node or both?

Is there some sort legend for colors, shapes, arrows etc. ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185598/rqt_graph-colors-and-arrows/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as i know, every publish/subscribe has its own arrow, even if nodes are forming a pub/sub loop.

for color code :

- Red box : Topic
- blue circle : node publishing under the topic
- Green circle : node subscribing to that topic

---

Originally posted by [Captcha](https://answers.ros.org/users/14366/captcha/) with karma: 61 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-09**:
Anything you hover on becomes red. With stuff before that blue and after green. If there's bi-directional arrows, it shows up blue-green. So that can't be right ^.

I have seen orange / yellow too. The only thing I know for certain is topics are in boxes and nodes in ellipses.